# Подсчет кол-ва интервалов по единицам времени

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется df со столбцами:

```
 start (datetime) | end (datetime) | action (str)
```

start и end - дата-время начала и конца какого-либо действия, описанное в столбце action

Есть также временной интервал (pd.date_range) с промежутком в 1 час.

Необходимо определить сколько активностей попадает на каждый datetime в date_range с обязательным условием: start <= datetime < end

Сейчас процесс выглядит следующим образом:

```
# считаем кол-во активностей группируя по start и end
test_kk = df_kk.groupby(['start', 'end'])['action'].count().to_frame().reset_index()

for my_ind in test_c_df.index:
    # выносим datetime для удобства
    my_dt = test_c_df.loc[my_ind, 'datetime']

    # суммируем данные, которые подошли под условие
    test_c_df.loc[my_ind, 'KK'] = (test_kk[(test_kk['start'] <= my_dt) & (test_kk['end'] > my_dt)]['action']).sum()
```

Это происходит примерно за 7 секунд и, мне кажется, есть способ сделать это намного правильнее и быстрее, но, к сожалению, моих знаний пока недостаточно, чтобы прийти к лучшему варианту.

Буду очень рад, если подскажите и приведете пример хорошего варианта!

Comment: А к pandas обязательно привязываться? Можно предложить общечеловеческий алгоритм. Не исключаю, что  его легко переложить на pandas

Comment: на такие вопросы очень неудобно отвечать если в вопросе отсутствует пример входных и выходных данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)